# How do I resolve inconsistent Windows 10 DPI after a restart?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, fonts, dpi

Under "Display Settings" from the desktop context menu, there is a slider titled "Change the site of text, apps, and other items". I have two monitors, and I would like them both to use "100%" text size.

However, when turning my computer on at the start of the day, the text size is inconsistent, in particular the desktop icons render as if text size was set to "200%", when the rest of the UI is still rendering at "100%".

My current workaround is to open "Display Settings", change the font size to "200%", log out, log back in, change it back to "100%", then log out, then back in again. This makes the font sizes consistent, but is a pain to do. Is there a way to force Windows to actually use the "100%" setting consistently?

Another factor that might be at play is that my main monitor is quite large, a 2560x1600 30" monitor, which Windows recommends using at 1280x800. Perhaps Windows at startup is doing something funny with the resolution detection. Is there a way to change the way that Windows picks the recommended resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround, it is:

1. Right click on desktop, select Display Settings
2. Click Advanced display settings
3. Click Advanced sizing of text and other items
4. Click "set a custom scaling level (not recommended)"
5. Set "Scale to this percentage of normal size" to "100%"

This seems to override whatever automatic detection was causing some parts of the UI to be scaled to 200%.

Comment: Thanks, I still have this issue from time to time and this seems to work. The setting has moved to Right click on desktop, select Display Settings and then "custom scaling"